# Input not getting written to a file after a for loop

Tags: java

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Kazarian_MadLibs {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    File file = new File("Mad Libs 1.txt");

    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    System.out.println("Please provide a word for each of the following: ");

    PrintWriter answers = new PrintWriter("answers.txt");

    inputFile.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
    {   
        System.out.println(inputFile.nextLine());
        keyboard.next();
        answers.println(keyboard.nextLine());
        answers.close();

    }
```

after the for loop has finished executing all 18 lines, it doesn't write any of my answers to the "answers.txt" file. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: There are 4 exact answers (and more to come), pick one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `close` statement out of the `for` loop so that you're not closing the `PrintWriter` in each iteration. Also you're reading from the `Scanner` instance twice per iteration - just read the value once and write to file

```
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
    System.out.println(inputFile.nextLine());
    String answer = keyboard.nextLine(); // Assign variable here
    answers.println(answer);
}

answers.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You `close` the writer `answers` on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: it still isn't working! I moved it outside the loop and nothing is showing up inside the text file

Answer (score 0):

Afer the first run through the loop you are closing the writer. Move the `answers.close();` after the loop the close the writer after the loop has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `answers.close();` outside the loop.It should work fine then.